# How to subtract a percentage using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following price in a list:

```html
<ol>
    <li><ins>£100</ins></li>
</ol>
```

```js
var total = 0;
var getPrice = parseInt($("ol li ins").data("val"), 10);
var discount = -(total * getPrice/100); 
$('ol li ins').text('£' + -discount);
```

I'm trying to take away 10% from the total cost but I keep getting NaN - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You multiply by 0, it give 0..

Comment: There is no data attribute in your HTML

Comment: in your case, display £90?

Comment: I see no data attributes here. So likely `parseInt(undefined, 10) == NaN`

Comment: Also, NaN will be rerturned by parseInt if the passed value starts with a nonnumeric character. And... why are you putting the result in negative and then negative it again? Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `text` of the element, there is no `data-val` associated with the target element

```js
var total = 500;
var getPrice = parseInt($("ol li ins").text().replace('£', ''), 10);
var discount = -(total * getPrice / 100);
$('ol li ins').text('£' + -discount);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>
    <ins>£50</ins>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: ...or just add `data-val="100"` and it works for any currency.